# another’s person or another person?

Tags: expressions, meaning-in-context, phrase-usage

I am doing a little bit of research in the library about negligence (a tort or civil wrong in UK/US legal systems) and I have read this sentence:

*Negligence goes beyond the ordinary English concept of ‘carelessness’ or ‘lack of attention’, and describes the unintentional interference with another’s person or property.*

I would like some help with this construction: *with another’s person*. It does not sound natural to me. And I do not understand it.
I would expect something clearer, such as *with another person or another’s property*.

Opinions/Clarification?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because because it belongs on ELL as it is a basic question about the possessive in English.

Answer (score 3):

'Interference with another’s person or property', means 'interference with somebody else's body and clothes or property'.

*Another's* is the possessive form of 'another' (somebody else). For example, theft is taking the property of another (or another's property).

> Another
>
> a person other than oneself or the one specified:
> *He told her he loved another*

[Another (The Free Dictionary)](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/another)

Person here means *body or clothes*

Legally, and in old-fashioned English, someone's 'person' is their body, possibly including their clothes.

[Person (Merriam-Webster Dictionary)](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/person)

> Person
> 4 b
> the body of a human being
> also : the body and clothing
> *unlawful search of the person*

Comment: This is not a legal term at all: Another person's property is not your property. The OP does not know how to use the possessive in English and this question should go to ELL.

Comment: @Lambie - you are misreading it. 'Another's person' is the person of another. To negligently interfere with the person of another could be to carelessly injure them or damage their clothing. To negligently interfere with another's property could be to act without sufficient care or attention so that something belonging to them was damaged. Put it all together: _unintentional interference with another’s person or property_. Normal English and recognisably from a legal text book.

Comment: "another's person" isn't an entirely obvious term, at least if you're wondering why it's used rather than "interference with another person or their property". "Person" normally means something figurative or abstract, rather than referring to the body: M-W's senses of *person* include "human, individual", "subject of rights and duties", "a character or part in or as if in a play", and theological and lingustic meanings.

Comment: @StuartF - Yes. Here 'person' is not abstract. A fellow asked me for a light, but I didn't have any matches or a lighter about my person.

Comment: @Lambie *This is not a legal term at all:* No, but it most commonly encountered in a legal context. The English is somewhat archaic to the modern ear, but it has a precise meaning: "to the person" = "to the body of a person". The distinction is between the less serious damage or injury to a possession or the more serious injury to the body.

Comment: @Greybeard Yes, "interference with another's person" means, as you say, interference with the other's body, clothing, or, possibly, even a backpack or handbag.  This is as opposed to interference with another's car or house which is less intimate although still upsetting.